# Matlab equality not working

Tags: matlab

```
x=0.008+0.005
if x==0.0130
    disp('hurray');
end
```

The above equality doesn't satisfy for these specific set of numbers 0.008 and 0.005, though it works for 0.009 and 0.004.

Comment: Floating point comparison need to be handled in a different way :)

Comment: something like `abs(x-0.0130)<1e-14`